# Gekko: Is it not possible to use logical conditions sequentially in Gekko Python?

Tags: gekko

I coded a model in Gekko and faced an error. So, I started checking line by line and found an issue that I couldn't understand. The code below (partial model code is shown, input file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FyWf2NktTuRg6RM1urqXHxPlMvJ7iJb-/view?usp=sharing)) can be executed, and the result is also correct. However, when I uncommented the 31st line, an error occurs. Would it be because I used the logical conditions (`ab3`, `max3`) sequentially? Is there any way to solve this issue?

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

# Read weather data
weatherData = np.load("Atlanta_TMY3_climate.npy")

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.open_folder()
print(m.path)

weatherData = np.insert(weatherData, 0, np.zeros((1,15)), 0)

days_to_consider = 1
m.time = np.linspace(0, 24*days_to_consider, 24*days_to_consider+1)

# Declare parameters
focc = m.Param(value = [0,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.1,\
                        0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,\
                        0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1], name="focc")

setpoint = [16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, \
            16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.38, 17.43, 17.88, 18.08, 18.35, \
            17.85, 17.13,16.27, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00]
T_air_set  = m.Param(value=setpoint, name="T_air_set")
Te         = m.Param(value = weatherData[0:24*days_to_consider+1,0], name="Te")
qv_infil_wind  = m.Param(value = 0.0769*0.6*(0.75*0.8* \
                         weatherData[0:24*days_to_consider+1,1]**2)**0.667,\
                         name="qv_infil_wind")

# 1) Airflow
qv_mech_sup     = m.Intermediate(2.519244226731981*focc*1, name="qv_mech_sup")

qv_infil_stack = m.Intermediate(0.0146*0.6*(0.7*8.5* \
                                m.abs3(Te-T_air_set))**0.667, \
                                name="qv_infil_stack")

# When below line code is uncommented, an error occurs.
##qv_infil_sw = m.Intermediate(m.max3(qv_infil_stack, qv_infil_wind) + \
##                             0.14*qv_infil_stack*qv_infil_wind/0.6, \
##                             name="qv_infil_sw")

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 4
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000
m.solve(disp=True, GUI=False)
```

Comment: Yun Joon, you need to specify your equations `m.Equation()` and the objective function `m.Obj()`.

Comment: Junho, Thanks for your reply. The reason why I didn't have m.Equation() and m.Obj()is I wanted to show only some snippets of my code for the sake of clarity. The code is incomplete but it is executable The gist of my question was when abs3 and max3 functions are used sequentially, I had an error that I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

I switched to `m.options.SOLVER=1` because the `m.abs3()` and `m.max3()` functions require a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) solver. However, this didn't solve the problem either. It appears that there is a combination of binary variables from each that is difficult to solve. I'm not exactly sure why but it is a solver issue, not a Gekko formulation issue. Here is a simple problem that shows that it isn't a problem to have `m.abs3()` and `m.max3()` in the same model and as a dependency.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Param(2)
y = m.Param(3)
z = m.abs3(x-y)
w = m.max3(z,x)
m.solve()
print(z.value[0],w.value[0])
```

There is a successful solution by switching to `m.abs()`. This avoids the solver convergence problem. I typically don't recommend using `m.abs()` but all of the dependent variables are parameters so there isn't a problem with non-continuous gradients.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read weather data
weatherData = np.load("Atlanta_TMY3_climate.npy")

# create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
print(m.path)

weatherData = np.insert(weatherData, 0, np.zeros((1,15)), 0)

days_to_consider = 1
m.time = np.linspace(0, 24*days_to_consider, 24*days_to_consider+1)

# Declare parameters
focc = m.Param(value = [0,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.1,\
                        0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,\
                        0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1], name="focc")

setpoint = [16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, \
            16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.38, 17.43, 17.88, 18.08, 18.35, \
            17.85, 17.13,16.27, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00]
T_air_set  = m.Param(value=setpoint, name="T_air_set")
Te         = m.Param(value = weatherData[0:24*days_to_consider+1,0], name="Te")
qv_infil_wind = m.Param(value = 0.0769*0.6*(0.75*0.8* \
                         weatherData[0:24*days_to_consider+1,1]**2)**0.667,\
                         name="qv_infil_wind")

# 1) Airflow
qv_mech_sup    = m.Intermediate(2.519244226731981*focc*1, name="qv_mech_sup")

qv_infil_stack = m.Intermediate(0.0146*0.6*(0.7*8.5* \
                                m.abs(Te-T_air_set))**0.667, \
                                name="qv_infil_stack")

mx = m.max3(qv_infil_stack, qv_infil_wind)    
qv_infil_sw = m.Intermediate(mx+0.14*qv_infil_stack*qv_infil_wind/0.6, \
                             name="qv_infil_sw")

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 0
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000
m.solve(disp=True, GUI=False)

plt.plot(m.time,mx.value,color='orange',lw=2)
plt.plot(m.time,qv_infil_stack.value,'r:')
plt.plot(m.time,qv_infil_wind.value,'k:')
plt.show()
```

I understand that this is a simplified version of the problem but you could pre-calculate all of these variables as Numpy arrays if they are all based on constant `m.Param()` types. This would avoid the extra inequality constraints and binary variables from the implicit solution.

Comment: In the given code, I initially got an error and the output says ``'GEKKO' object has no attribute 'max'``'. However, I was able to successfully execute by switching the ``'max``' to ``'max3``'. I appreciate your kind answer.

Comment: Thanks for catching that - I've updated my response with your correction.